# Angular, syncing two select elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm struggling to understand binding and and select elements. I want two select elements to be synchronized. It seems as though ng-value="$index" should be the correct way, but it doesn't work.

**These sync:**

```
<select  ng-model="myVar1"><option value="{{n}}" ng-repeat="(n, o) in ['donny', 'felix', 'bob'] track by $index" >{{o}}</option></select>
```

{{o}}

**but these dont:**

```
<select  ng-model="myVar2"><option ng-value="$index" ng-repeat="o in ['donny', 'felix', 'bob'] track by $index" >{{o}}</option></select> <select  ng-model="myVar2"> <option ng-value="$index" ng-repeat="o in ['donny', 'felix', 'bob'] track by $index" >{{o}}</option>   </select>
```

JSBIN:
http://jsbin.com/dirugikice/1/edit?html,js,output

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your $index in brackets, e.g `{$index}`

```
<select  ng-model="myVar2"><option ng-value="{$index}" ng-repeat="o in ['donny', 'felix', 'bob'] track by $index" >{{o}}</option></select> <select  ng-model="myVar2"> <option ng-value="{$index}" ng-repeat="o in ['donny', 'felix', 'bob'] track by $index" >{{o}}</option>   </select>
```

http://jsbin.com/pubapigibi/1/edit

Comment: in the first example is option value asigned to key value and as you are iterating array, the key value is index of the item array. Select display value is the object "o" (string) itself.

Comment: Thanks, though I don't get the logic and can't find documentation on that